# msvcp120d.dll missing when trying to run on visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2013, dll, visual-studio-2015

I had Visual studio 2013 installed and had my code running on it.
A few months ago I installed Visual studio 2015 and debugged my project there.
A week ago I decided since I'm no longer using Visual studio 2013 to uninstall it.
Ever since I have not been able to run my code in debug mode in 2015. I have tried cleaning my project and rebuilding it (my code has no dependencies on other compiled codes). I have also tried installing Visual studio 2013 redistribute pack but I still get an error that msvcp120d.dll is missing when I try to launch the debug version of my code.
Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: you still use a lib/DLL that is compiled as debug in VS2013, so you depend on the debug C++ runtime of VC++2013

Comment: That's very weird, i don't think that i need to. Is there a way to find out which lib/dll?

Comment: I used dependency walker and found out that I used an HDF5 library that was compiled with VS2013. I guess rebuilding the HDF5 library should solve the problem.

Comment: ok,does the rebuild with VS2015 fixes it?

Comment: yes thank you, works great now.

Comment: ok, answer your own question whith the steps you did to fix it

Comment: I rebuilt the hdf lib files with VS2015 and linked against them and it worked.